# Subsetting a dataframe based on surrounding row values

Tags: r, for-loop, indexing, subset

I am analyzing data collected on bird behavior and want to calculate the amount of time a seabird remains on the surface of the water while loafing, otherwise considered resting, between foraging dives (diving under the water to pursue fish). The data is in this form currently.

```
structure(list(alt_id = c(10L, 10L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
    act = c("l", "d", "l", "d", "l", "d", "l", "d", "l", "d", 
    "l", "d", "l", "d", "l", "d", "l", "d", "l", "d"), action_time = c("15", 
    "0", "5", "24", "10", "0", "43", "28", "16", "37", "9", "35", 
    "15", "34", "11", "0", "12", "33", "15", "33")), .Names = c("alt_id", 
"act", "action_time"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

This subset of data contains behavior information on 4 different individuals (indexed by the unique id number). I need to first evaluate the dataframe so that I am only considering the behaviors of the individual birds. To do this I need to make sure that the id number directly below the row I am considering is the same. I then need to isolate the times when the bird is loafing (indicated by "l" in the database). I then want to make sure that it dove (indicated by "d") both before and after the loafing period. By doing this I am ensuring that I am not counting the times when the bird is just happily floating on the water as loafing between dives as they may do this for hours at a time after they are full.

Ideally this would run in a for loop or some other expression allowing me to run through all 4,000 plus rows of data at once creating a vector of loafing (l) times that I can then use to calculate mean, sd, etc. on.

Any tips on how to accomplish this?

Comment: What would be the result of your sample data?

Comment: To be specific, bird #10's data would be excluded, right? ...and line 3 would not be added to the total because there is no dive before the first loafing period, right?

Comment: the result of the sample data would be a vector only containing the action_time that were "l" and bounded by "d" on either side (of the same bird id.

Comment: sorry meant to start a new line it would look like vector<-c(10,43,16,9,13,11,15)

Comment: What about "d" ==0? Why does that count as a dive? And why is 43 in there?

Comment: you are right 43 should not be in there. As for "d"==0, this indicates that the bird transitioned from "l" to "d" but I was not able to see the bird when it came back to the surface (lost in an ice floe or came up within a group of other birds. These 0's indicate an observation ended due to factors other than the 10 min observation protocol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's call this data "loafers". If this were not to be done "by bird", you would throw out the first and last lines because their predecessor and successor could not be determined and do this:

```
dtest <- function(dfrm) dfrm[c(FALSE, 
                               dfrm$act [2:(nrow(dfrm)-1)] =="l" &
                               dfrm[ 1:(nrow(dfrm)-2), "act"] =="d" &
                               dfrm[ 3:(nrow(dfrm)), "act"] =="d" ,
                               FALSE) , ]
```

Applying to the full data and again throwing out first and last lines within bird:

```
lapply( split(loafers, loafers$alt_id), dtest)
$`2`
   alt_id act action_time
19      2   l          15

$`10`
[1] alt_id      act         action_time
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

$`12`
  alt_id act action_time
5     12   l          10

$`13`
   alt_id act action_time
9      13   l          16
11     13   l           9
13     13   l          15
15     13   l          11
```

Answer (score 2):

Although DWin answered the question I asked I continued down the path I had been on prior to the answer (with some tips of how to frame the for loop) and came up with this. This vector is one observation less than the original data set but after adding one more FALSE it can be appended and used to subset off of as this was just a small part of a bigger problem. The larger dataframe I am working with is called 'land'

```
rest <- function(x)
{
    output <- vector(length=NROW(x$alt_id)-1)
    for(i in 2:(length(x$alt_id)-1))
    {
    if(x$alt_id[i]==x$alt_id[i+1] &&
    x$alt_id[i]==x$alt_id[i-1] &&
    x$act[i]=="l" &&
    x$act[i+1]=="d" &&
    x$act[i-1]=="d")
        {
        output[i] <- "TRUE"
        }
        else
        {
        output[i] <- "FALSE"
        }
    }
    return(output)
}

resting <- rest(land)
resting <- append(resting,"FALSE")
land <- cbind(resting, land)
```

The second to line of the code justs adds one more FALSE to the vector as this line was not evaluated but by nature of the question cannot be a resting time. The final line appends the new vector 'resting' to the original database.